# Вычисление логических выражений заданных в виде строки

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь реализовать фильтрацию входных данных. Хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь вводил в виде строки какое-то логическое выражение типа `(x > 100 && x < 120) || x ==42`. В коде x заменится на конкретную константу. Собственно вопрос как это вычислить? В принципе `QScriptEngine::evaluate()` замечательно справляется с этой задачей, но тянуть в проект целый Qt Script ради одной строчки кода это сильно круто, по-моему.

Короче, можно ли как-то обойтись без Qt Script, и при этом не писать с нуля свой собственный парсер?

Comment: 1) можно отдать строку внешней утилите, например, предварительно подставив переменные. 2) Пример калькулятора на Qt есть в документации.

Comment: @PinkTux Вариант со внешней утилиткой еще хуже - это надо за собой утилиту таскать. В системах с пакетным менеджером проблем нет (хотя, там и с Qt проблем нет), а вот в форточке...

Comment: Вы можете сами реализовать прасинг этой строки через конечный автомат. Может быть вы найдёте в интеренет готовые реализации такой функиональности.

Comment: @PinkTux, Калькулятор из документации выполняет операции по мере того как пользователь вводит их(так же как калькулятор из Windows). Это не совсем то

Comment: Вам нужен парсер, но готовый вы не хотите, а писать самостоятельно тоже нет. Можно воспользоваться каким-нибудь генератором парсеров (например, lex/yacc), но вам придётся тогда выучить их. There's no free lunch.

Comment: @VladD, я хочу готовый. Но в Qt я знаю только QScriptEngine. Это не просто решалка выражений, а целый парсер JavaScript. Не хочется такую машину в проект тянуть только ради разбора пары выражений

Comment: А как насчёт [QExpressionEvaluator](http://radekp.github.io/qtmoko/api/qexpressionevaluator.html)?

Comment: @AivanF. Вообще это то, что нужно, но "The Qt Base module offers classes for embedded Linux devices". Если я правильно понял, под виндой этого нет, а проект кроссплатформенный.

Comment: BTW, безумная идея :) Берём PicoC или TCC, формируем что-то типа `char s[] = "int foo(int x) { return (x > 100 && x < 120) || x == 42; }"`. Передаём это дело как строку в API интерпретатора и получаем результат :) Технология чуть отличается в обоих случаях (API немного разный),  но принцип и результат - те же. Зато и возможностей намного больше.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека [muParser](http://beltoforion.de/article.php?a=muparser) замечательно работает с Qt, причем даже с переменными и функциями